# How Do I JOIN a third Table called all_recipes using recipe_id KEY

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
SELECT COU.recipe_id, IFNULL(FOU.Found, 0) AS Found, COU.Count
FROM  ( SELECT recipe_id, COUNT(recipe_id) As Count 
        FROM recipe_ingredients 
        GROUP BY recipe_id) COU
LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT R.recipe_id, COUNT(R.key_ingredient) AS Found
        FROM users_ingredients U
        JOIN recipe_ingredients R ON R.key_ingredient = U.key_ingredient
        GROUP BY R.recipe_id) FOU ON FOU.recipe_id = COU.recipe_id
```

I need to Join three tables together - well, 4 in the end. Can someone please show me how I can do this and explain how to keep joining when required later. I will have 4 or more tables. Many Thanks

Credit to @Arulkumar for Above

Comment: Can you show your tables relationship schema, to see exactly what your trying to do ?

Comment: How do I do that? I haven't done database Design since year two of uni... few years ago @user3502626 What do You need mate?

Comment: Ok, just explain me about the three tables. Write the fields in each one of the three tables and Tell me what you want to do.

Comment: I want to be able to join all 3 tables
already joined two by key_ingredients
now need to join the other by recipe_id
And eventually get the images for the steps from image table
If that makes sense mate

// RECIPE_INGREDIENTS
recipe_id int(11)   
ingredients_id int(11)   
key_ingredient varchar(100)   
ingredient_description varchar(100)

//USERS_INGREDIENTS
product_id int(11)   
user_id int(11)   
barcode varchar(13)   
title varchar(100)   
category varchar(100)   
key_ingredient varchar(100)   
valid tinyint(1)

Comment: I am not sure if you are seeing a problem where there isn't one: you can join as much as you want: `select .. from ... join ... on ... join ... on ... join ... on ... join ... on...  where ...`. Have you tried that and didn't succeed? Because I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Ok, try this. I have never tested that code but, but I'm sure it will work.

Comment: You can join any much table you want. Just use join and on the condition you want. I do not see the third table. But you could just do `JOIN third_table tt ON tt.recipe_id = first_table_or_segond_table.recipe_id`

Comment: `SELECT COU.recipe_id, IFNULL(FOU.Found, 0) AS Found, COU.Count, img.id AS imgId, img.src AS imgSRC, U.product_id, U.user_id,... FROM recipe_ingredients COU [LEFT] JOIN users_ingredients U ON COU.key_ingredient = U.key_ingredient [LEFT] JOIN image img ON img.recipe_id = COU.recipe_id`

Comment: join all 3 tables
And eventually get the images for the steps from image table
// RECIPE_INGREDIENTS
recipe_id int(11)   
ingredients_id int(11)   
key_ingredient varchar(100)   
ingredient_description varchar(100)

//USERS_INGREDIENTS
product_id int(11)   
user_id int(11)   
barcode varchar(13)   
title varchar(100)   
category varchar(100)   
key_ingredient varchar(100)   
valid tinyint(1)

//ALL_RECIPES
recipe_id int(11)   
title varchar(100) 

//ALL_IMAGES
image_id        int(11)
recipe_id int(11)   
image_path varchar(100) 
recipe_step     int(11)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your SQL does but, to join another table you need to do something like this.

```
SELECT recipe.id, all_recipes.id 
FROM recipe 
LEFT JOIN all_recipes ON recipe.id = all_recipes.id
```